# In angular form is getting submitted without form value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, rxjs, angular15

Below Is my html and ts code I have added settimeout for 2seconds to get the response and append to form without which value is not getting appended.
Please provide any alternate solution if we can avoid settiemout here

```js
export class ABCComponent implements OnInit {

  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  amount: any;
  samlResponse: string | undefined;
  @ViewChild('hiddenForm') hiddenForm: ElementRef | undefined;

 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const routeSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe({
      next: (params: Params) => {
        this.amount = params['val']
      }
    })
    this.subscriptions.push(routeSubscription);
    this.onPageLoad();
  }

  onPageLoad(){
    let payload ={
      "val":this.val
    }
   
    this.service.api(payload).subscribe( {
      next: ((response: any) => {
        this.res = response.res;
       setTimeout(() => {
        this.submitForm();
       }, 2000);
      }),
      error: (value: any) => { 

      }
    }
    )}

    submitForm(){
        this.hiddenForm?.nativeElement.submit();
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-center container-fluid min-vh-100">
<form #hiddenForm method="post" action="example.com"
(ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <input type="hidden" [value]="res" name="res">
<button type="submit" style="display: none;">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="text-center w-100 fs-4"><b>Redirecting...</b></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check the angular documentation on how to use angular forms: https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app/first-app-lesson-12